# iOS 9.1 Crashes App when Accessibility Inspector is On

Tags: ios, crash, uiaccessibility, hockeyapp

I am using HockeyApp for crash reporting.  I noticed a crash that is happening frequently and only with iOS 9.1.  The crash occurs when a text field becomes the first responder which also triggers a UITableView delegate to be set.  At first I struggled to reproduce, but now I can reproduce all the time.  All I have to do is turn on the Accessibility Inspector and my app will crash.  The reason for the crash is, "Reason: Selector name found in current argument registers: _accessibilitySetRetainedValue:forKey:" and it the crash is a "SIGSEGV".  Any thoughts on how this can be fixed?

Comment: Does your `UITableView` already have a delegate and you're setting a new delegate on it?

Comment: Yes.  The UITextField is used for searching and the delegate changes so it needs to be updated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We ran into something similar that wound up being caused due to something like the following:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<UITableViewDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableVIew *tableView;

...

self.delegate = newDelegate;
self.tableView.delegate = newDelegate;
```

The original delegate gets deallocated, which normally wouldn't be an issue. But as far as we can tell, when accessibility is enabled, something in there has an `assign` reference to the original delegate, and when the new delegate is set, there's something that tries to clear that reference. Which doesn't exist anymore.

TL;DR: Don't deallocate the original delegate before assigning the new one to the tableview:

```
self.tableView.delegate = newDelegate;
self.delegate = newDelegate;
```

Comment: This is exactly what's happening.  Thanks!

Comment: Ran into this same thing, except with VoiceOver itself on device. My best guess was that VoiceOver might be adding *strong* references to certain objects so that it can keep speaking if needed (or something). In the multi-strong reference scenario, you've always had to nil out your weak delegates and such...I guess we are now in a situation where we need to nil out delegates even for single-strong scenarios, since VoiceOver may add other strongs to the mix. Again, that's not confirmed that it does, but smells kinda like it. Perhaps a reference-counting test could be done!